# NVDA accessibility

Tags: html, wai-aria, nvda

I'm improving the accessibility of the component but when assigning the ARIA attributes the NVDA screen reader introduces "BANNER MARCO" before any sentence.

```
 <ani-button  class="modal-close" kind="tertiary"><span aria-label="Fechar janela modal"></span>
</ani-button>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your `<ani-button>` is but the "banner" announcement is because you have a banner landmark.  That might be because you have a `role="banner"` on an element or you're using the `<header>` element.  NVDA will announce the landmark type when you navigate to the first element in that landmark.  It should not repeat it for every element in the landmark.

For example,

```
<header>
  <button>one</button>
  <button>two</button>
  <button>three</button>
</header>
```

When you <kbd>tab</kbd> to the first button, you'll hear "banner **landmark**, one button".
When you <kbd>tab</kbd> to the second button, you'll *just* hear "two button" without "banner".
When you <kbd>tab</kbd> to the third button, you'll just hear "three button" without "banner".

(It looks like "landmark" is translated to "marco" in Portuguese, as shown in your screenshot.)

If you <kbd>tab</kbd> backwards to the third button, you'll hear "banner landmark, three button".

Comment: yes in my structure I'm using a header tag I think that's why, thanks in advance for the explanation. @slugolicious thanks !